# Void pointer to access structs in char array

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

I have a buffer, essentially an char array, filled with multiple different structs. The structs needs to be passed in a buffer like this because it is something I read/write to a socket. The structs are one header struct and possibly "multiple payload" structs.

Just to illustrate, it looks like this:

```
unsigned char buffer[buflen];
struct header *head;
struct payload1 *p1;
struct payload2 *p2;

etc...
```

Now, when I try to fill this buffer, or retrieve from this buffer, I've used a `void *ptr` where it is first initialized at the position of the buffer then later at the position after the header, like this:

```
void *ptr;

ptr = &buffer;
ptr += sizeof(header);
```

This actually works fine - i.e. the pointer points to the correct memory location and I can retrieve (or insert) a new payload struct just fine, but it does however generate a warning in gcc. `warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic`.

What can I do to avoid this warning in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use char * instead of a void *. The problem is it's not obvious what incrementing a void * is supposed to do. I'd expect this to be an error rather than a warning.

Comment: I know char is usually 1 byte long, therefore this will work on most systems, but I thought it wasn't properly defined?

Comment: @espengra sizeof(char) is defined by the C Standard to be 1. What is not defined is performing pointer arithmetic on void *.

Comment: char is defined as the smallest addressable type in the C99 standard.  If some obscure operating system defines a char as other than 8 bits, it will still be taken to be a "byte"-sized variable type.  This is rare though, and generally can be ignored.

Comment: -1: `sizeof(void)` yields `1` and the compiler allows pointer arithmetic but not dereferencing.

Comment: @Blagovest - You are wrong. That works as a GCC extention. The standard explicitly prohibits pointer arithmetic on `void *` pointers.

Comment: @Chris: I'm not saying "the standard defines `sizeof(void)` to be `1`", but rather "`printf("%zu", sizeof(void))` outputs `1` when compiled with GCC without any options supplied" - that's different.

Comment: @Blagovest: and now you've limited yourself to GCC and compilers that try to be compatible with GCC.

Comment: @Blagovest - You're implicitly making a statement about the C language behaves when you say "`x` yields `y`". Without prior qualifications, people expect GCC (a C compiler) to conform to the C language as specified. If a certain behavior is a compiler extension, it should be clearly noted. Unless someone clearly asks about compiler extensions, we should assume they're talking about the standardized (and _portable_) version of the C language rather than any related dialect.